# How to split data into a dictionary?

Tags: python, xml, dictionary

I am reading data from xml file from that i have to build dictionary. Data of xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<University>
    <Form> 
    <RNlength>10</RNlength> 
    <ROLLNUMBER>
        0-0,A-1,A-2,0-3,0-4,A-5,A-6,A-7,0-8,0-9,
        1-0,B-1,B-2,1-3,1-4,B-5,B-6,B-7,1-8,1-9,
        2-0,C-1,C-2,2-3,2-4,C-5,C-6,C-7,2-8,2-9,
        3-0,D-1,D-2,3-3,3-4,D-5,D-6,D-7,3-8,3-9,
        4-0,E-1,E-2,4-3,4-4,E-5,E-6,E-7,4-8,4-9,
        5-0,F-1,F-2,5-3,5-4,F-5,F-6,F-7,5-8,5-9,
        6-0,G-1,G-2,6-3,6-4,G-5,G-6,G-7,6-8,6-9,
        7-0,H-1,H-2,7-3,7-4,H-5,H-6,H-7,7-8,7-9,
        8-0,I-1,I-2,8-3,8-4,I-5,I-6,I-7,8-8,8-9,
        9-0,J-1,J-2,9-3,9-4,J-5,J-6,J-7,9-8,9-9,
        K-1,K-2,K-5,K-6,K-7,L-1,L-2,L-5,L-6,L-7,
        M-1,M-2,M-5,M-6,M-7,N-1,N-2,N-5,N-6,N-7,
        O-1,O-2,O-5,O-6,O-7,P-1,P-2,P-5,P-6,P-7,
        Q-1,Q-2,Q-5,Q-6,Q-7,R-1,R-2,R-5,R-6,R-7,
        S-1,S-2,S-5,S-6,S-7,T-1,T-2,T-5,T-6,T-7,
        U-1,U-2,U-5,U-6,U-7,V-1,V-2,V-5,V-6,V-7,
        W-1,W-2,W-5,W-6,W-7,X-1,X-2,X-5,X-6,X-7,
        Y-1,Y-2,Y-5,Y-6,Y-7,Z-1,Z-2,Z-5,Z-6,Z-7
    </ROLLNUMBER>
    </Form>
</University>
```

From above .xml file, i have to extract data based on length of the string. By extracting "RollNUMBER" element information, i have to split data by comma(,). After that extract information where '0-0' means before '-' represents label, after '-' represents column number. Total number of column is equivalent to length of string. For given .xml data, dictionary should look like,

```
data = [
    {"0":0,"1":1,"2":2,"3":3,"4":4,"5":5,"6":6,"7":7,"8":8,"9":9},
    {"0":"A","1":"B","2":"C","3":"D","4":"E","5":"F","6":"G",.......,"24":"Y","25":"Z"},
    {"0":"A","1":"B","2":"C","3":"D","4":"E","5":"F","6":"G",.......,"24":"Y","25":"Z"},
    {"0":0,"1":1,"2":2,"3":3,"4":4,"5":5,"6":6,"7":7,"8":8,"9":9},
    {"0":0,"1":1,"2":2,"3":3,"4":4,"5":5,"6":6,"7":7,"8":8,"9":9},
    {"0":"A","1":"B","2":"C","3":"D","4":"E","5":"F","6":"G",.......,"24":"Y","25":"Z"},
    {"0":"A","1":"B","2":"C","3":"D","4":"E","5":"F","6":"G",.......,"24":"Y","25":"Z"},
    {"0":"A","1":"B","2":"C","3":"D","4":"E","5":"F","6":"G",.......,"24":"Y","25":"Z"},
    {"0":0,"1":1,"2":2,"3":3,"4":4,"5":5,"6":6,"7":7,"8":8,"9":9},
    {"0":0,"1":1,"2":2,"3":3,"4":4,"5":5,"6":6,"7":7,"8":8,"9":9}
]
```

where, key of dictionary is index of value.
I implemented it but i am not getting idea how to extract data in dictionary format.

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse('demo.xml')
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('ROLLNUMBER')
pattern = itemlist[0].firstChild.nodeValue

l = [x.strip() for x in pattern.split(',')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that your expected ouput should be `"25": "Z"` because A is indexed from 0

Then, you can acheive this by splitting the token again and converting the second part to integer.
Here the inner loop ensure the column number contain a dictionnary before use.

```
l = []
for x in pattern.split(','):
  x2 = x.split('-')
  label = x2[0]
  col = int(x2[1])
  while len(l) < col + 1:
    l.append({})
  l[col][str(len(l[col].keys()))] = label
```

Live test: 
https://repl.it/IMoU/1